# Getting query string arguments in order in Python

Tags: python, query-string

I have a server program getting query string arguments like the following:

> http://www.example/page.py?a=10&b=5&c=6

I need to concat the arguments on order i.e. I need a string that contains a + b + c. I try to access the query string arguments as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import cgitb
import urllib.parse
import sys, os

cgitb.enable()

# Print necessary headers.
print("Content-Type: text/html")
print()

query = os.environ.get('QUERY_STRING')
query = urllib.parse.unquote(query, errors="surrogateescape")
query_components = dict(qc.split("=") for qc in query.split("&"))
for k,v in query_components.items():
    print(k)
```

When I print the keys, I get the order:
    c a b

Is it possible to extract the query string arguments in order ?

Comment: Dictionaries in python do not maintain insertion order. They store data by hashing to ensure fastest retrieval of data. To maintain order use [ordered dict](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ordereddict-in-python/).

Comment: Is there any reference code on how to extract a ordered dict from query string ?

Comment: Did you try `collections.OrderedDict(qc.split("=") for qc in query.split("&"))`?

Comment: This one worked. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) instead of dict when you define query_component

> An OrderedDict is a dict that remembers the order that keys were first inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
query_components = OrderedDict(qc.split("=") for qc in query.split("&"))
for k,v in query_components.items():
    if '?' in k:
        print(k.split('?')[1],v)
    else:
        print(k,v)
```